# Explode or split a utf-8 string but keep delimiters attached to string

Tags: php, regex

I would like to transform a string into an array of elements delimited by commas or period, but where each element keeps its delimiter.  For example, the first sentence to the preamble of the US Declaration of Independence would become:

- When in the Course of human events,
- it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another,
- and to assume among the powers of the earth,
- the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them,
- a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.

What would be an efficient way to do that?  I know how to save into an array both the pieces and the delimiters, using `preg_split` with the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag, but I'm not sure if there is a way to keep the commas and periods appended to the sentence fragments in one operation.

I guess a more accurate way to describe what I want is a `preg_split` where the delimiter would be anything **preceded by a comma, a period, etc**.  I'm not sure whether regex would allow that...

And I need this to be utf8-friendly.

Comment: Are you looking for a 1-liner? You can use `preg_match_all` but that will include trailing spaces, which can be deleted using a foreach loop for the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
if (preg_match_all("/([^.,!?]*[.,!?])/", $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.  I wasn't aware of this function! Why is `$matches` an array of array?

Comment: @JDelate: `matches[0]` contains the text matching the full pattern, then each index will contain each captured subexpression. So if you have one capturing group, for example, which is the case here, matches will contain two entries.

Comment: I'm not following.  `matches[0]` and `matches[1]` seem to contain exact duplicates of the array of substrings...

Comment: @JDelage: because the entire regex is wrapped in a single parenthesis. Try another regex, such as `"/(\w)*(\s)*/"` and you'll get a very different array.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it.  Your regex is made up of a unique parenthesized subpattern.  Therefore, there is no difference between the array that captures the text matching the full pattern, and the array that captures the text matching the 1st parenthesized subpattern.  Had the regex been made of 2 parenthesized subpatterns, the array would have contained 3 sub-arrays, one for the full regex, one for the first subpattern, and one for the 2nd subpattern.

Comment: Quick follow up question - do we not need a `/u` somewhere in the regex to allow for utf-8?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like the following:

```
$str = 'asdf, qwer, zxcv, uiop';
$arr = preg_split('/(,)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$tmp = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i += 2) {
    $delim = isset($arr[$i + 1]) ? $arr[$i + 1] : '';
    $tmp[] = $arr[$i] . $delim;
}
print_r($tmp);
```

Which prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => asdf,
    [1] =>  qwer,
    [2] =>  zxcv,
    [3] =>  uiop
)
```